# How to add multiple foreign keys into one column of a table?

Tags: mysql

I'm thinking on how to build a lecture-student relationship. Let's say I have:

- A table called students with each student having a studentid.
- A table called lectures that has a studentid field and also a lectureid.

Is it possible to have in the lectures table, within the studentid column multiple IDs, like 1,2,3,4,5 which would means that when anyone of those student IDs log into the system, they will see the specific lecture?

My logic is probably flawed but I'm quite new to MySQL and I'm thinking how I can avoid having one lecture record per studentid.

Comment: It is possible to store array of data in the table column. Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567916/mysql-store-array-of-data-in-a-single-column it will definitely help you.

Comment: You can check my answer. It will give you some idea.

Comment: @Nepal12, no, don't do that - you'll get into a right pickle. This is a many to many relationship, and it needs a joining table.

Comment: Agreed. It's definitely not the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have 1-to-1 relationship, you can put the foreign key (student id) right into the lecture table. but since each lecture may have many students, and each student may have many lectures, you would need a joining table as others suggested.

You *can* put multiple ids into a "cell", but it's messy and does not leverage the value of the relational database system. MySQL has a native way of doing what you want, but it is still messy and not ideal.

As far as the CASCADE options, they would be set where you have the foreign keys: in the join table. The join table has 2 columns: "student_id" and "lecture_id". You probably don't want a non-existent id staying in your join table. E.g., if a student drops out of school and their student id is deleted, why would you want their id in your join table matching them with various lectures? You probably wouldn't, so you would set them to ON DELETE CASCADE so that their entries in the join table are removed.

For lookups, you simply need to get values from your main tables based on what's in the join table. If you want to show a student every lecture they are in, you would do something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM `lectures_table`
RIGHT JOIN `lectures_students` ON lectures_students.student_id = 5 # // you already have their id b/c they are logged in
AND lectures_table.id = lectures_students.lecture_id
```

Now you have a complete set of data from the lectures table, limited to the lectures the student is enrolled in.

If you want all the students in a lecture (perhaps for your own perusal), you would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `students_table`
RIGHT JOIN `lectures_students` ON lectures_students.lecture_id = 27 # // you have the lecture id because that's what you clicked on to view
AND students_table.id = lectures_students.student_id
```

Comment: Thanks. This made it straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a joining table. It would be just another table with one key referencing the lecture and the second one referencing the relevant student. You'd have one row per student-lecture relation. What it does is it prevents from deleting anomalies, for example when you delete a student he probably shouldn't be on a list of any lecturer. You can configure the DB in such a way that it cascades the delete, so the moment you delete your student, all his entries regarding lectures vanish. Not to mention that performing queries over such a database is going to be much less difficult than using the 1 cell version.

Comment: Thanks for that, but if in the table I have as I said a lecture record per studentid, and if the cascade is on delete, it will still clean up the lecture table when the user is deleted. So my question is, is there much point making another table apart from maybe keeping it cleaner?

Comment: What about when you remove a lecture? You still have a problem of using one cell. Processing it is going to be painful. What about counting the number of people enrolled for a lecture? A DBMS can do it really fast, you are going to dumb it down to string processing.

Comment: Removing a lecture by lecture id? You reckon that's too messy?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a student. You are going to have to write your own procedures for that. And pretty much everything else. What if you one day want to expand that system and add something like `majors` and then say that all the student with major in maths are to take functional analysis? Enforcing that with proper relational system is trivial, not so much when you put everything in one cell.

Comment: Yes, don't put things in one cell. Use the join tables for many-to-many relationships. Deleting and updating is much easier that way. And setting up the join table is only slightly harder than setting things up the messy way.

Answer (score 1):

I would use one more table called like 'StudentLectureMap' and make studentid and lectureid mapped. 
Also, if you do it with foreign key reference, so no one can delete lecture or student before deleting the map between them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy solution for you. Create three tables : student, lecture, student_lecture. You have to create a "junction" table.

```
student
student_id (Auto increment and primary key)
student_name

lecture
lecture_id (Auto increment and primary key)
lecture_name

student_lecture (after you added student_id and lecture_id, make sure you create indexes and assign the student_id and lecture_id as a foreign key from their tables)
student_id (foreign key from student table)
lecture_id (foreign key from lecture table)
```

phpMyAdmin, step by step.

1. Your structure should look like this:

[image]

2. Your junction table. Click "index" for student_id and lecture_id.

[image]

3. After you create indexes, click "relation view" and select main tables and click save. Voila!

[image]

After you do this, you'll be able to add more than one lecture per student. For example, student A can take lecture 1, lecture 2, lecture 3. Also student B can take lecture 1, lecture 2, lecture 3.

Also you can watch this video to understand better: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A42FG4LzdbY.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example:

```
<?
// use this to store in database // You can insert Ids inside this array I mean instead of foo, bar etc you can use ids.
$array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
mysql_select_db("mysql_db",$conn);
$array_string=mysql_escape_string(serialize($array));
mysql_query("insert into table (column) values($array_string)",$conn);
?>

<?
// use this to get data from database
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
mysql_select_db("mysql_db",$conn);
$q=mysql_query("select column from table",$conn);
while($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
$array= unserialize($rs['column']);
print_r($array);
}
?>
```

Dont forget to `serialize and unserialize` the array while storing and retrieving the data.