# how to save value of formarray in mysql with nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have a problem and I want someone to help me.  
My English is not that good, I'm sorry about that I'll try my best to explain the problem to you hopefully u can help me and thank you.

I'm working on an activity management platform where an employee login to his account and chose a project, then a table contains the days of a certain month under each day there is an input where he enters 1 or 0 if he worked that day or not this is how the UI looks:

[image: this is how the UI look like]

When he clicks the button VALIDER (Validate in French) the data entered should be saved in mysql database.
to collect the data I used FormBuilder in angling, I defined as a form group that contains a form control that should get the name of the project, a form control that gets the month, and one for the year, and a form array that should get the values of the 3 inputs, when I console.log the value of the form I get this:


[image: console.log(this.form.value)]

when I try to save the data in my database, I get the message successful, but when I look at my database nothing gets stored,
my database contain a table with :
projectName: varchar(45),
month: number,
year: number,
days: JSON

I think that the problem is that days are an array and not of type Jason because I tried saving an array, but I did like this: insert into project (projectName, days) values ('nomProjet', '['0', '0', '0']') and it gets saved but my days Array doesn't.
my node js code for the backend :

```js
app.post('/cra/add', function (req, res) {
    let nomProjet = req.body.projet;
    let year = req.body.year;
    let month = req.body.month;
    let days = req.body.days;
    if (nomProjet && year && month && days) {
        connection.query('INSERT INTO projetcra2 ( nomProjet, month, year, days ) SET ( ? , ? , ? , ?) ',
            [nomProjet, month, year, days],
            function (error, results, fields) {
                res.send({ status: 'success' , days});
                res.end();
            });
    } else {
        res.send({ status: 'failed', message: 'some data are required', loggedin: false });
        res.end();
    }
});
```

my formbuilder :

[image: formBuilder]

my save function to save to the database :

```js
addDaysWorked() {
    this.api.cra(this.form.value).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
      }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
 }
```

when i test with postman :

[image: Postman]

my database :

[image: database]

I hope my problem is explained, if u think I can help with anything else let me know and thank you.

Comment: if you console.log in you node.js file where the function runs to save to the database,do you actually receive data?

Comment: i added console.log(days) to my code, and when i make a post request i do get the data in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert at backend stuff by any means. However, I believe storing items as an array is inside of a single column in a database is not ideal. You should consider creating a new, separate table, for just days worked.

In the table, you could have a column that specified the date, whether or not he/she worked, and link obviously link this using a foreign key (*like* userId) to the users table or the main table in this case.

This would allow you to more easily insert the data. Since each day would just be a simple row, querying would also be simpler as you would just query data given a Timeframe (example: from beginning of August - End of August), a user (unique user ID).

Here are a couple other generic [stack questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313417/whats-the-best-way-to-store-the-days-of-the-week-an-event-takes-place-on-in-a-r) that might clarify as well.

Hope this helps!

Check out [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18568180/15492085) as well